# Is the kernel not smart enough to drop some of the cache for the blocks of the same file that have already been read?

Tags: linux, caching

I used `read` to read a 2G file in a `for` loop. After 80% of the file has been read, the program was blocked in the system call '**read**', due to no more RAM for caching.

When no enough RAM can be used for caching anymore, is the kernel not smart enough to drop some of the cache for the blocks of the same file that have already been read, or just stop caching for reading the remainder of the file?

Comment: Show your code - what language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

How would the Linux Kernel know what is your use case for the `read` system call? It is just aware of system calls like `read` and `write`. Read implementation is the same weather it is used to copy a 2G file, or it is used by firefox when you switch to a tab for example.

If you need that functionality you can either disable caching (I think something like this: `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`), or create a new system call that "enforces" that some application's read-write calls doesn't deal with memory cache (I had such a project when I was an undergrad).